# Использование wait() вызывает IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, синхронизация

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
```

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка в том, что или в поток входят объекты, которые не помечены как `synchronized` или(возможно - и) если такой объект изменится, пока работает `wait`, то после окончания wait, этот поток может использовать измененный из другого (в моем случае - ui) потока объект. Но кого тогда помечать как `synchronized`, надо ли это вообще, и почему все работает, если не использовать wait, не понятно.

**Код:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public boolean cycleShouldContinue;
public int counter;

TextView currentCountTextView;

Thread thread;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

    currentCountTextView = findViewById(R.id.currentCount);

    cycleShouldContinue = true;
    iterationCycle();

}

synchronized public void iterationCycle(){
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (cycleShouldContinue){
                counter++;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        currentCountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    }
                });

                try {
                    thread.wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
    
}
```

Вообще цель - сделать явный экземпляр `Thread`, чтоб можно было обращаться к нему и вызывать его методы из других мест в программе. (Ведь можно описать новый поток, как будто не выделяя ему имени,но и обратится можно только раз, интересно, как это называется:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }).start();
```

---

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call) советуют в первом ответе создавать дополнительно класс-блокировщик какой-то, а как он привязан к моему потоку или нужно наследовать этот клас от `Thread` или как, вообще ничего не понятно.

Comment: Да, в wait запрещено входить не из synchronized-блока того объекта, на котором вызывается wait

Comment: мне почему то кажется, что вы хотели сделать секундную задержку, но вместо статического метода Thread.sleep(1000) (статический метод sleep вызовет метод sleep на текущий поток), вызвали wait

Comment: @DaysLikeThis ,не совсем. Планируется,что секундная задержка может прерваться методом notify().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо вызывать метод `wait` is синхронизированного блока, поскольку у синхронизованного метода используется другой монитор.

```
synchronized(thread) {
    try {                   
        thread.wait(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Заработало, причем для меня непонятно почему. Тоесть, из хабра я знаю что на один объект выделяется один монитор, только зачем этот "другой" монитор, и за кем он закреплен(за экземпляром thread?) и где об этом можно почитать поподробнее?

Comment: за екземпляром класса, может быть он и не нужен...